# Invalid syntax for discord bot (python)

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

[On the bottom left it says that I'm using Python 3.6 64-bit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Ah0g.png)
Im trying to create a discord bot and copied and pasted this code from an example, but for some reason it does not seem to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
#Python 3.6
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
import asyncio

bot = commands.Bot(commands_prefix='#')

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('!hello'):
        msg = 'Hello {0.author.mention}'.format(message)
        await client.send_message(message.channel, msg)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as')
    print(client.user.name)
    print(client.user.id)
    print('------')

client.run('token')
```

The error I get is:

```
[Running] python -u "/Users/brady/Documents/tempCodeRunnerFile.py"
  File "/Users/brady/Documents/tempCodeRunnerFile.py", line 12
    async def on_message(message):
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

[Done] exited with code=1 in 0.092 seconds
```

I am trying to run this code in Visual Studio Code

Comment: What is the full error message?  Is the indentation here identical to that of the code you're attempting to run (specifically the `client.run` line)?  Not related to your question, but why are you using both `Bot` and `Client`?

Comment: I have edited the post to show the error message. Also, the indent on the client.run line has been fixed to match the actual code. I am not sure for the Bot and Client as I have copied and pasted this code, if you could help me in figuring out which to use that would be helpful.Thanks again @PatrickHaugh

Comment: Are you sure you're using python 3.6?  Try `python -V`

Comment: I added a picture of the code showing that my version is on 3.6 @PatrickHaugh

Comment: I've tested your code and it runs fine on my machine, apart from changing `commands_prefix` to `command_prefix`. Have you tried saving the file and running it directly from command prompt/terminal?

Answer (score 0):

You used

```
bot = commands.Bot(commands_prefix='#')
```

So to make it work you will need to use

```
@bot.command()
```

else it won't work.

Also the

```
Client = discord.Client()
```

part here is useless